# How to Pass Original PBKDF2 Hash from SQLite3 DB

Tags: hash, sqlite, pbkdf2

I know that there are a lot of questions on PBKDF2 and hashes, but most of them seem to talk about bits. Perhaps that is what I need to learn more about, but I'm hoping there is something more straight-forward for my problem.

Note: These are two separate programs (so the variables will seem to repeat, but do not).

The first creates a hashed password and stores it in the db ... This is working fine.

```
from pbkdf2 import crypt
import sqlite3

cemail = input("Email: ")
cpassword = input("Password: ")
pwhash = crypt(cpassword)
connection = sqlite3.connect('/Users/Air/Desktop/users.db')
cursor_v = connection.cursor()
cursor_v.execute("insert into user (cemail, cpassword) values (?,?)", (cemail, pwhash))
connection.commit()
cursor_v.close()
```

The problem is here, where I go to check the database for the original hashed password. Once the hashed password went into the database from the first program, is that it? Is it gone forever (i.e. not able to be compared to something else later, like another password during login)?

```
cemail = input("Login with Email: ")
cpassword = input("Login with Password: ")
pwhash = crypt(cpassword)
connection = sqlite3.connect('/Users/Air/Desktop/users.db')
cursor_v = connection.cursor()
cursor_v.execute("SELECT * FROM user WHERE cemail=? AND cpassword=?", (cemail,pwhash))
row = cursor_v.fetchone()
if pwhash == crypt(pwhash, cpassword):
    print("Welcome")
else:
    print("Invalid")
```

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: The correct usage for `crypt` when checking passwords is `crypt(alleged_pw, real_pw_hash)`; you should not `crypt` the attempted password at all. Change your filter to filter only based on the email (which should be unique).

Comment: Hi Colonel Thirty Two. Thank you for your help. I'm sorry, would you elaborate, I'm having trouble understanding how to implement what you wrote. Could you kindly give me an example with my code?

Comment: There's an example on the python-PDKDF2 homepage: https://www.dlitz.net/software/python-pbkdf2/

Comment: Hi Colonel Thirty Two. I hate to bother you again. I am trying to follow your steps. I changed the filter so now only have email and also removed the first crypt(cpassword), but am still confused, even after reading the website. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi Colonel. I had to think about what you were saying a little more, and think I got it! Thank you again!